# Convert string to time stamp and specific format using Shopify's Liquid

Tags: templates, shopify, liquid

In liquid template

```
input "2019-06-11T08:54:28Z" {{ article.published_at }}   
-> is outputing "6/11/2019 8:54:28 AM"
```

What I wanted was to format the date. in (yy/mm/dd hh:mm)and I have tried this

```
{{ article.published_at | date: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" }} and 
{{ "2019-06-11T08:54:28Z" | date: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" }}
```

but what this did not work I keep getting "2019-06-11T08:54:28Z" 
am I missing something?

Comment: What do you get when you try this {{ "now" | date: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" }}?

Comment: `{{ page.published_at | date: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" }}` - it works fine for me. Are you changing code in right place? (Just to be sure :))